# Difference in duration of audio file converted from WAVE to MP3

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I think there should be no difference in total time duration of play back of an audio file if we convert it between different formats.

For example if I record wave file of total time duration for 2 seconds, its size now is 20.3 MB . now i convert this wave file to mp3 file using ffmpeg latest build it becomes 1.35 mb in sizes. Now I get the time duration of the same converted MP3 file  using below code.

```
public static String getDurationWithMp3Spi(File file)
            throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, Exception {

        AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
        System.out.println(" File for duration MP3 " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        if (fileFormat instanceof TAudioFileFormat) {
            Map<?, ?> properties = ((TAudioFileFormat) fileFormat).properties();
            String key = "duration";
            Long microseconds = (Long) properties.get(key);
            int mili = (int) (microseconds / 1000);
            int sec = (mili / 1000) % 60;
            int min = (mili / 1000) / 60;

            String mp3Len = null;
            String mins = null;
            String secs = null;

            if (min == 0) {
                mins = "00";
            }

            if (min < 10) {
                mins = "0" + min;
            }else{
                mins = "" + min;
            }

            if (sec == 0) {
                secs = "00";
            }

            if (sec < 10) {
                secs = "0" + sec;
            }else{
                secs = ""+secs;
            }

            mp3Len = mins + ":" + secs;

            System.out.println("time = " + min + ":" + sec);


            return mp3Len;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException();
        }

    }
```

If I see in windows media player or any other player it will show the same duration as it is for original wave but when I get from this method it is different from originals and the difference is very big.

Is there in difference in time duration of audio file if it is converted from WAVE to MP3 or vice versa?

Any help please. the above code uses [MP3SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) plugin.

the above method does the conversion and get the duration.

```
for (Iterator<FileItem> fileIter = fileList.iterator(); fileIter
                .hasNext();) {

            FileItem fileItem = fileIter.next();

            // write file to disk to specified path
            if (!fileItem.isFormField()) {

                String fileName = fileItem.getName();

                System.out.println(" file Name " + fileName);

                // save file to desired destination
                waveFileSavePath = processFolderAppendee(waveFileSavePath,
                        fileName);

                File waveFile = new File(waveFileSavePath);

                fileItem.write(waveFile);

                Thread.sleep(100);

                // do conversion
                String mp3FileName = fileName.replace("wav", "mp3");
                mp3Path = mp3Path + "/" + mp3FileName;
                convertToMP3(servletContext, waveFileSavePath, mp3Path);

                Thread.sleep(100);

                // prepare data(s)
                GuestMessagesForm guestMessageForm = prepareGuestMessageData(
                        accountId, waveFileSavePath, mp3Path);

                PlayListMessagesForm playListMessageForm = preparePlayListMessageData(accountId);

                // save data(s)
```

// this method calls duration
                    saveGuestMessage(guestMessageForm);
                    savePlayListMessage(playListMessageForm);

```
            } else {

                // do nothing
            }

            waveFileSavePath = servletContext.getRealPath(recordDir);
        }
```

Comment: The duration should not change.  Do the files play for the same time in VLC or the OS' media player?  Do those players report the time correctly before the sound plays?  After?  Does the MP3 use VBR?  That can confuse players (or SPIs) until they have loaded the track from start to end.

Comment: fixed bit rate 192k. when i start the media player or vlc player and play converted mp3 file it takes some time to display the duration , but after that both player shows the same duration.when i run the above code from my editor , means out side of server it gives the exact duration as of wave. i think it might be the problem of i immediately call the above method after conversion methods, so it may happen that when i get the duration of an mp3 file , it is still not being converted properly and i get the wring duration, i am posting the method in my code above which do it.

Comment: *"..am posting the method in my code above which do it."* If it is an answer, it would e better to post it as the answer and accept it.

Comment: but for that i need to confirm first from an expert like  you .

Comment: please look at my method and tell me if you agree with me as this is the problem of immediate method call ??

Comment: To comment further I'd need an SSCCE from you, and an environment set up with the appropriate APIs.  I have neither.